# Days, hours, minutes, seconds between two dates

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have two dates, one less than the other.  I want to create a string such as this one

"0 days, 0 hours, 23 minutes, 18 seconds"

representing the difference between the two dates.  How can I get these elements of this string?

Comment: thanks guys - I wish I could accept all your answers but that's not allowed so I've upvoted all your answers.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) is the object you need:

```
TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now);

String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", 
    span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
```

Comment: but will this give me days, hours, minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 14):

When you subtract one [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) from another, you get a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instance, which exposes those values.

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today;
string formatted = string.Format(
                       CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                       "{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", 
                       diff.Days, 
                       diff.Hours, 
                       diff.Minutes, 
                       diff.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class, which you'll get when you subtract the dates.

You can format the output using [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) format strings.

> "0 days, 0 hours, 23 minutes, 18 seconds"

can be had with something like:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine(
   string.Format("{0:%d} days, {0:%h} hours, {0:%m} minutes, {0:%s} seconds", ts)
);
```

IMO, it's cleaner and easier to use `string.Format` instead of having to escape the words in your format string (which you'd need if you just used `.ToString`) or building it up manually.

Answer (score 6):

Use a TimeSpan

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );

TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );

String yourString = string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minues, {3} seconds",
    span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that if you want this calculation to be portable you need to store it as UTC and then when you display it convert to local time. As a general rule Store dates as UTC and convert to local time for presentation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using

```
TimeSpan()
```

that can certainly do what you want

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
    TimeSpan diff = dateTimeNew - dateTimeOld;
    string output = string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minues, {3} seconds", diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    DateTime myDay = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime otherDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    var test = otherDate.Subtract(myDay);
    Console.WriteLine("Days:" + test.Days + "Hours:" + test.Hours +"Minutes" +  test.Minutes +"Seconds" + test.Seconds);
```

Here test is of type TimeStamp

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, _.TotalSeconds_ will return the **total** number of seconds, so a 1 hour timespan will return 3,600 TotalSeconds.  The _.Seconds_ property will return 0 seconds as there are none "leftover" in a 1 hour timespan.

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeSpan diffTime = dateTimeNew -PreviousDate;
int days=diffTime.Days;
int hours=diffTime.Hours;
int minutes=diffTime.Minutes;
int seconds=diffTime.Seconds;
```

Comment: OP wants to build a string from the result of the calculation. That part is missing from your answer.