# How to get Difference hours Between two date

Tags: c#

I want get diffrences **Day**,**Hour** and **Day** between two days.

I use belowe Code :

```
DateTime LastDate = DateTime.Parse("2/12/2015 11:24:23 AM");
int differenceDay = DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastDate).Days;
int differenceHoure = DateTime.Now.Hour - LastDate.Hour;//returns -11
int differenceMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute - LastDate.Minute;
```

When I want get Hours its return mines (-11 e.t).

How can I get positive Diffrence Hour ?

anyone can you help me?
I want get Last Dat and show its by string how days afterd now.

Comment: Next time, please use Google first instead of directly asking a question here. You _may_ find your answer in 30 seconds.

Comment: @sloth: No, that's *not* a duplicate. That's asking for the difference *just* in hours. This is asking for "days, hours and minutes".

Comment: @JonSkeet This would be a better duplicate IMO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538507/days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yes, that would be reasonable - although it wouldn't explain what was wrong with the OP's current approach.

Comment: @SonerGönül @ JonSkeet I agree that's a better duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're subtracting component-wise (i.e. "this hour-of-day minus that hour-of-day, this minute-of-hour minus that minute-of-hour"). Don't do that - it won't work if the current hour-of-day is earlier than the hour-of-day of `lastDate`, or the same for minute-of-hour - you get a negative value, exactly as you've seen.

Instead, subtract one `DateTime` from another to get a `TimeSpan` and use that single `TimeSpan` for *all* the components:

```
DateTime lastDate = DateTime.Parse("2/12/2015 11:24:23 AM");
TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now - lastDate;
int days = difference.Days;
int hours = difference.Hours;
int minutes = difference.Minutes;
```

That will still be negative if `lastDate` is after `DateTime.Now`, of course.

Note that this will give you a result which is meaningful if you display all three components. For example, it might give you "2 days, 3 hours and 10 minutes". If instead you want to represent the same `TimeSpan` as "2.194 days" or "51.166 hours" or "3160 minutes" then you can use `TotalDays`, `TotalHours` and `TotalMinutes`.

If you *always* want a positive `TimeSpan` - the equivalent of `Math.Abs` but for `TimeSpan` you can just use `TimeSpan.Duration()`:

```
TimeSpan difference = (DateTime.Now - lastDate).Duration();
```

Comment: this line `int hours = difference.Hours;` ites return **-10**  How can I get posetive number for example I want get **10** instedof **-10**

Comment: @job1393: Why would you want 10? The difference *is* -10 hours. If you want to just always have a positive TimeSpan and ignore which is earlier, you can just invert the `TimeSpan` - I'll edit to show that.

Comment: You can also use the  [`TimeSpan.Duration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the absolute value.

Comment: last hour is **11 am** and now is **00 pm** it sould be returns **one hour insted of **-10**

Comment: @job1393: By "00pm" do you mean midday? It doesn't help that we don't know what time zone you're in. Are you saying it's currently 2015-02-12T12:00:00? If so, I'd expect the result to just be 36 minutes. I suspect your problem is really a time zone one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Nice - I'd never seen that before! (Which surprises me, given the amount of time I've spent with the date/time APIs...)

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution

```
TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now);
```

String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds",
span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);

[in this link](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/c-days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates/)