# Calculate time until Weekday

Tags: c#, datetime

How could  calculate the time until the daytime of the next weekday?
More specifically I want to calculate the minutes, hours, and days until the next Wednesday at 14:00.

How could I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Days, hours, minutes, seconds between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538507/days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates)

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how to get the current day and time? Subtract other values? Do you know how to get the next Wednesday?

Comment: Just subtract the next weekday from current time.

Comment: You can get answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time?rq=1

Comment: If today is *Wed 11:00* what is the right answer? *3 hours* or *7 days 3 hours*? What's the right answer for `Wed 15:00`?

Comment: I don´t see why upvoting this question that shows no own appraoches at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel like taking risk to answer that but..

> How could calculate the time until the daytime of the next weekday?

If you mean Wednesday with this sentence, you can iterate current date to next Wednesday with [`DayOfWeek` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) like;

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
while (today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
{
    today = today.AddDays(1);
}
```

Since I'm in İstanbul right now -today is Wednesday- and this code returns today, not 7 days after.

> More specifically I want to calculate the minutes, hours, and days
>   until the next Wednesday at 14:00.

Then you can add `14` hour to today and get difference between current local time ([`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)) with it.

```
today = today.AddHours(14);
TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now - today;
Console.WriteLine(difference.ToString("d\\.hh\\:mm"));
```

By the way, this [`TimeSpan.ToString(string)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) added with .NET Framework 4.0 version. If you use .NET 3.5 or below, you can use [`Days`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Hours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Minutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties (or maybe `TotalXXX` properties) of your `difference`.

Answer (score 1):

That you need is a `TimeSpan` object:

```
TimeSpan duration = nextWednesday  - currentDate;
```

where `nextDay` and `nextWednesday` are two `DateTime` objects representing the dates you are interested in.

For instance, `currentDate` could be this `DateTime.Now`. For `nextWednesday` you need something more:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var daysUntilWednesday = ((int) DayOfWeek.Wednesday - (int) today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
var nextWednesday = today.AddDays(daysUntilWednesday);
var ts = new TimeSpan(14,0,0);
nextWednesday = nextWednesday.Date + ts;
```

Having done that, you can use the properties of `TimeSpan` object to get that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
DateTime t1 = ......;
DateTime t2 = ......;
TimeSpan ts = t1.Subtract(t2);
```

> A TimeSpan object represents a time interval (duration of time or
>   elapsed time) that is measured as a positive or negative number of
>   days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second. The TimeSpan
>   structure can also be used to represent the time of day, but only if
>   the time is unrelated to a particular date.