# Get the Number of Hours Between Two Times In Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan, tryparse

I have a 3 textbox in .aspx.
1. txtStartTime
2. txtEndTime
3. txtNumberOfHours

I want to auto calculate number of hours in **txtNumberOfHours**

Here is my Code :

TestNumOfHour.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" ontextchanged="txtStartTime_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndTime" runat="server" ontextchanged="txtEndTime_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumberOfHours" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

NumOfHour.aspx.cs

```
  protected void txtEndTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNumberOfHours.Text = calculateTimeDiff(txtStartTime.Text, txtEndTime.Text).ToString();
    }
    protected void txtStartTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNumberOfHours.Text = calculateTimeDiff(txtStartTime.Text, txtEndTime.Text).ToString();
    }

    private TimeSpan calculateTimeDiff(string t1, string t2)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Zero; 
        DateTime tt1, tt2;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(t1, out tt1) && DateTime.TryParse(t2, out tt2))
        {
            ts = tt2.Subtract(tt1);
        }
        return ts;
    }
```

I only want **Hours** exclude Minutes and seconds but somehow I getting this result.

> The Result in txtNumberOfHours : hr:mins:seconds

Comment: Are the inputs "abstract times of day" or (date)times on *particular* days? If the latter, do you need to take DST into account?

Comment: Look into `TimeSpan.Hours` and into `TimeSpan.ToString(string)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Days, hours, minutes, seconds between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538507/days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates)

Comment: You might also want to consider making this all less "stringly-typed". There's no reason why the `calculateTimeDiff` method should be parsing strings. It's inputs should be `DateTime`s already.

Comment: What is the expected result if startTime is `00:00:00` and so is endTime? What if startTime is `00:00:00` and endTime is `23:59:59`? What if startTime is `23:00:00` and `endTime` is `01:00:00`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txtNumberOfHours.Text = (t2 - t1).TotalHours.ToString();
```

This statement is returning the number of hours.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(DateTime.Parse(t2) - DateTime.Parse(t1)).TotalHours
```