# How to subtract two datetime values and get the output in HH:MM:SS format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, function, datetime, formatting, azure-sql-managed-instance

I want to subtract two datetime values and the output in HH:MM:SS format.

If the difference is more than one day, the days count needs to be added to hours.

I tried to concat the datediff outputs as mentioned below

```
select concat(datediff(hh, '2019-07-16 04:45:03.000','2019-07-17 19:38:13.000')
,':',
(datediff(mi, '2019-07-16 04:45:03.000','2019-07-17 19:38:13.000') -(datediff(hh, '2019-07-16 04:45:03.000','2019-07-17 19:38:13.000')*60))
,':',
(datediff(ss, '2019-07-16 04:45:03.000','2019-07-17 19:38:13.000')-(datediff(mi, '2019-07-16 04:45:03.000','2019-07-17 19:38:13.000')*60)))
```

Expected output: `38:53:10`

Actual output: `39:-7:10`

Can you tell me what mistake I made? Is there a better way to get the required output?

Comment: `time` doesn't support values over 24 hours. You'll be better off returning the difference in seconds and having your display layer worry about the formatting, or similar. What application are you using for the display layer? That's what you *should* be tagging here.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538507/days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates

Comment: @Larnu Oh okay fine, thanks you. The answer provided by David Browne works fine.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with that solution, @Venkat, is that it returns a `varchar`, and as a result, the "time" `'11:00:01'` with be **after** `'100:00:00'`.

Comment: Oh, and it uses `FORMAT`, which (i'll be honest), is a terribly poor performer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
with q as
(
  select datediff(SECOND, '2019-07-16 04:45:03.000','2019-07-17 19:38:13.000') secs
), hms as
(
  select secs/60/60 as hours,  (secs/60) % 60 as minutes , secs % 60 seconds
  from q
)
select concat(format(hours,'00'),':',format(minutes,'00'),':',format(seconds,'00') ) hms
from hms
```

which returns

```
38:53:10
```

Comment: Browne Thank you so much, this works fine. I have a couple for questions, can you please clarify.? 1.) What's wrong with the query which i has posted? 2.) What does " format(hours,'00') " do?

Comment: Careful with `FORMAT`; it perforums awfully. You would be far better off avoiding it.

Comment: If perf is critical, something like `right(concat('00',hours),2)` would be faster.

Comment: That would be far better, in my opinion @DavidBrowne-Microsoft .

Comment: Why do I have to use format here, what would be the issue with just concatting hours, minutes and seconds from hms in the query directly.

Comment: Just string formatting.  You can use whichever you prefer.  The example had all 2 digit numbers, so it was unclear which format was required.